# Azure Service Bus http vs websocket

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am making use Azure Service Bus for microservice to microservice communication . I understand that the topic sends the messages to all of the clients whenever it receives a message .

Does the azure service bus uses websockets instead of HTTP?

Also does it have any retry mechanism if one client goes down temporarily?

Comment: Are you interested in knowing how a Topic publishes a message to its Subscriptions or how the clients can fetch the messages from Subscriptions?

Comment: @GauravMantri: I am interested to know the difference between websocket vs retry mechanism in azure service bus implementation

Comment: I’m not sure if they’re even related.

Comment: @GauravMantri: ok Does Azure service bus uses websockets for communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Communication:**

Azure Service Bus implements `AMQP` or `NetMessaging` as the messaging protocol.

Both messaging protocols can use `TCP`, `HTTP` or `HTTPS` as the underlying communication protocol.

`TransportType` enum sets the messaging protocol.

`ConnectivityMode` enum sets the underlying communication protocol.

**Retry mechanisms:**

Retry mechanisms can be set using the `RetryPolicy` class.

The class contains `ExponencialBackOff`, `NoRetry` and `Default` as built-in implementations.

**More information:**

[Retry guidance for Azure services - Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#service-bus)

[TransportType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.transporttype?view=azure-dotnet)

[ConnectivityMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode?view=azure-dotnet)